# Setcontent method present in mimemessage class is not able to render my .VM file's html content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, velocity

Suppose I am using velocity macro file as a template to send HTML content as a mail body.

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.init();

Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("index.vm");

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("name", "World");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
t.merge( context, writer );
```

When I pass writer.toString() and "text/HTML" in `message.setconent` method, mail body is coming as empty.

While if I do pass a hard coded HTML tags as a string it's able to render.Please advise.I have tried number of things,still facing the issue.eg 
`message.setconent("<HTML><h1>hello</h1></html>", "text/HTML")`--its working fine

But message.setcontent(writer.tostring(),
"text/HTML") ...it's not rendering the HTML content in my mail body.

If you think my VM file is not getting loaded I tried to analyze that too. its getting loaded properly. As I could see if I send mail like below.

```
Message.setText(writer.tostring)
```

It gives me a mail with full VM file content with HTML tags and everything.

Please help me

Comment: Are you sure the returned value from write.toString() contains the correct html?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show when you send the message?  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: I  am using javax.mail 1.4.7  . Javamail debug output,I am not sure why it is.And yes write.tostring() is returning whole html output

Comment: Yes I checked debug mode too...

Comment: If the JavaMail debug output shows the correct message content being sent to the mail server, but the message content is missing when you read it later, the problem must be in the mail server.

Comment: I got the issue.Its not able to render head content.I removed title tag,Now it's working fine. Now I am anther issue when using css properties.I am not creating any other css file.I put it in head section.But when I am using it for the alignment of two tables.Its not able to do.Tables should be side by side but they are coming vertically.Any guess?

Comment: See if [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) helps.  If not, create a new post with the details of your new problem.